# How to change address and name of the computer in linux Ubuntu

Tags: updates

I have troubles again after upgrading Linux to version 12.04 - When I try to update progams and files with "apt-get update" it says something like there is no address added to your computer name. So my hostname has name "Marco" and my hosts file has line "127.0.0.1 Marco" So where is problem? Where should I change my name to get it right for updates? Thank you. Before on version 11.10 it was working fine.

```
W: Failed http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en Something bad happened in the translation "en.archive.ubuntu.com: http" (-5 - The machine name is not assigned to any address)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is with the nameserver(s).
After updating to 12.04 there is no resolv.conf file, these settings are being configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`

For instance if this was you resolv.conf
    nameserver 10.10.10.10
    nameserver 10.10.10.20

No you need to rewrite it like this in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
dns-nameservers 10.255.255.10 10.255.255.20
```